# How to get the element lists between two index numbers in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a list such as :
set a {zero mean0 one two mean1 three four five mean2 six seven eight nine ten mean3 12 13 14 15}

Now i want to automate my code such that it creates different lists such as:

```
list1 {mean0 one two}
list2 {mean1 three four five}
list3 {mean2 six seven eight nine ten}
list4 {mean3 12 13 14 15}
```

Is there any way to do it in tcl? Any guidance would be appreciated!!

Comment: I'd recommend you store the sublists in a list, not in individually named variables.

Comment: Are you planning to use variables `list1`, `list2`, etc? If so, please don't! Use an array instead (`list(1)`, `list(2)`, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lsearch` to find the indices of all elements that start with "mean". Add the length of the list for the last part. Pick the first index off the list as a starting point, then loop over the rest of the indices. The `lrange` command can give you the partial lists. The end index of one iteration will be the starting index for the next iteration.

Combined, it could be coded as:

```
foreach p2 [lassign [linsert [lsearch -all $a mean*] end [llength $a]] p1] {
    puts [lrange $a $p1 [expr {$p2 - 1}]]
    set p1 $p2
}
```

Comment: The indices can be expressed with an offset: `lrange $a $p1 $p2-1` -- ref "string indices" http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M54

Comment: True, but that needs to shimmer the integer to a string, making it slower than using `expr`. It may not matter here, but I just stick to the habit of always using `expr`.

Comment: I'd prefer a double foreach: `foreach p1 [set idxes [lsearch ...]] p2 [list {*}[lrange $p1 1 end] [llength ...]] {`. It is longer, but much less tricky.

Comment: The answers really helped me with my issue. Thank you so much!!